# Why does passing a jQuery object to .replaceWith() replace the element with "[object Object]"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I've got a page with several li elements. I'm trying to replace one of those li elements with an array of elements using jQuery. When I pass either a jQuery object or array of jQuery objects to replaceWith(), however, the element is replaced with the string "[object Object]" for each item in the array.

```js
let newElement = $("<li class='myClass'></li>");
$("#myListItem").replaceWith(newElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li id="myListItem"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I expect to see:

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
<li class='myClass'></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Instead, I get:

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
[object Object]
</ul>
</div>
```

## EDIT:

@Barmar and @Bergi were correct in the comments below. Something is causing .replaceWith() invoked on jQuery objects to trigger the native .replaceWith() method. The output in the snippet below demonstrates exactly what I'm seeing when I run my code (except my code is ostensibly using the jQuery method).

```js
let newElement = $("<li class='myClass'>New li</li>");
let newElement1 = $("<li class='myClass'>New li</li>");
let newElement2 = $("<li class='myClass'>New li</li>");

let elementArray = [newElement, newElement1, newElement2]

document.getElementById('myListItem').replaceWith(elementArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li id="myListItem"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce that error. Your code works fine

Comment: Are you actually using [the native `replaceWith`  method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) instead of the jQuery method?

Comment: I'm calling replaceWith() directly on a jQuery object. Is there a way to check if I'm using the JQuery method vs native?

Comment: @chihwaro _“Is there a way to check if I'm using the JQuery method vs native?”_ — Of course: `console.log($("#myListItem").replaceWith === Element.prototype.replaceWith)`. `console.log($)` to make sure if `$` is jQuery or a [console helper](//firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/helpers/index.html). The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Check if jQuery even loaded.

Comment: What does `console.log($ == jQuery)` show? It seems like you may have aliased `$` to `document.querySelector`. Try using `jQuery("#myListItem")`

Comment: Hmm, if that were the case, `$("<li class='myClass'></li>")` would return `null`, not an object.

Comment: And the console helper version of `$` just gets an error with that argument.

Comment: console.log($=jQuery) returns true. jQuery is definitely loaded, I use it elsewhere in the codebase with no issues. I tried passing in a plain html string to .replaceWith() and .after() and it is rendering as a quoted [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) instead of an html element

Comment: Something in your code has modified `jQuery.fn.replaceWith` to be `Element.prototype.replaceWith`. This isn't the normal behavior.

Comment: @chihwaro `$=jQuery` or `$ === jQuery`? _“I use it elsewhere in the codebase with no issues”_ — That’s not a proof that it works _here, in this case_. Does the Network tab come with an HTTP 200 OK response? Does the Response tab show the jQuery library code?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, Sorry, typo, yes $ === JQuery returns true. Network tab shows HTTP 200 and the code appears in the response tab.

Comment: @chihwaro Can you make a [mcve] in your question, like the demo Barmar put in there? Without being able to reproduce the issue, we can only guess

Comment: Added an example showing what I'm seeing. @Barmar is correct in thinking that jQuery.fn.replaceWith is being rerouted to Element.prototype.replaceWith. I suspect that this is happening somewhere in a proprietary pipeline I don't have access to. Is there a way for me to explicitly point towards the correct method at the point of use?

Comment: Unless that proprietary code has assigned a new name to `$.fn.replaceWith`, you may be out of luck. Redefining jQuery methods is a horrible thing for them to do, it's likely to break lots of things, as you've discovered.